# Wordpress:Destroy session and redirect user instantly

Tags: wordpress, session

I have a script that allows just one concurrent wordpress-session by destroying all other active sessions of a user when this user is logging into wordpress:

```
add_filter('authenticate', 'wpse_12282015_single_login_authenticate', 0, 3);

function wpse_12282015_single_login_authenticate($user, $username, $password) {

    $user =  get_user_by('login', $username);

    if( isset($user->ID) ){

        if(isset($user->roles) && is_array($user->roles)) {

            //check for admins
            if(in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {

                // admin can log in more than once
                return $user;
            }
        }

        // get all sessions for user
        $sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance($user->ID);

        // destroy everything since we'll be logging in shortly
        $sessions->destroy_all();
    }

    return $user;
}
```

Now, I would like to add a function that automatically redirects the destroyed sessions, if open, to another page.

For example, if an user is logged in via the Chrome browser and is logging at the same time in Firefox, the page in Chrome should detect the destroyed session (for example through ajax-loops every 10 seconds) and redirects automatically to a page.

How could I achieve this?